# Cannot get value from Material UI DatePicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I'm new to react and now I wanna be able to have a reusable component for date input, but i cannot get the values back from the component to the register.

Here is my form code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import FDate from "../../Components/Forms/FDate";

function AltaArtista() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    try {
      console.log(data);
    } catch (e) {}
  };

  return (
    <div>
        <FDate
          label='Fecha de Nacimiento'
          register={{ ...register("nacimiento", { required: true }) }}
        />
        <Button variant='contained' type='submit'>
          date input
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here is my FDate component

```
import * as React from "react";
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
import DatePicker from "@mui/lab/DatePicker";
import AdapterDateFns from "@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns";
import LocalizationProvider from "@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider";

function Fdate(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(new Date());

  const handleDate = (newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
    console.log(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <DatePicker
        label={props.label}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleDate}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}

export default Fdate;
```

When I print newValue in handleDate I can get the time selected in datePicker, but the value that returns to the form is the date selected when the app starts and it doesn't change, any thoughts will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your Fdate component, you're not using the `register` prop that you're passing it down from AltaArtista. Form state is controlled by the `useForm` hook and so you don't need to separately control it inside of 'Fdate'. But you should set the default (initial) value of `nacimiento` when declaring `useForm`

```js
const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
  defaultValues: {nacimiento: new Date()}
});
```

and then spread your props inside Fdate:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
import DatePicker from "@mui/lab/DatePicker";
import AdapterDateFns from "@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns";
import LocalizationProvider from "@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider";

function Fdate(props) {
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <DatePicker
        {...props}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}

export default Fdate;
```